# call double click on mouse single click

Tags: vb.net, double-click, mouseclick-event

how do we call double click on single mouse click event? Iam doing this and it's not working. Any ideas ?

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.MouseClick
    RichTextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Comment: This should work.Are you getting any errors?. additionally you could try [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9555719/1189040)

Comment: "Not working" is a meaningless problem description.  Did you actually create the RichTextBox1_MouseDoubleClick method in your code?

Answer (score 0):

In properties windows click Event Icon and find double click and in selected event name select  "RichTextBox1_MouseClick"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.MouseClick, RichTextBox1.MouseDoubleClick, RichTextBox1.DoubleClick
    'Do stuff here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 options. The first is how your doing it, which the click can still do more as well as the double click.

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_MouseClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.MouseClick
    '' i can do stuff here
    RichTextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(sender, e)
    '' and here

    '' as well as do whatever double click is doing

End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.MouseDoubleClick
    '' to do something here
End Sub
```

The other option, if they are always going to do the same, you could do this:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_Single_DoubleClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.MouseClick, RichTextBox1.MouseDoubleClick
    '' do something here
End Sub
```

Notice the second Handles bit on the end? that function can handle both now :)

Either should work fine for what you want.